# Smalltalk syntax highlighting in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I'm trying to get sublime to highlight smalltalk `.st` files but am running into some trouble.

A quick search found [this package](https://github.com/DJviolin/sublime-smalltalk), but after adding the repository like it says in the README, I don't see the package that its supposed to add when doing `Package Control: install package`.

I also tried looking into [this one](https://github.com/lm/sublime-smalltalk-syntax) but am completely lost when it says `This syntax file can be converted to .tmLanguage using PackageDev 'Convert to PList'. Place the converted file in Packages/Smalltalk/Smalltalk.tmLanguage and reopen any .st file.`

Can anybody help me out please? I'm running ST3 on MacOSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installtion instructions using *Package Control* did not work for me either, but you can take the language file, `Smalltalk.tmLanguage`, from [Smalltalk syntax for Sublime Text 3](https://github.com/DJviolin/sublime-smalltalk) and use the manual installation instructions you cited:

> Place the file in Packages/Smalltalk/Smalltalk.tmLanguage

As you asked about macOS, on macOS this means:

```
/Users/<your user name>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Smalltalk/Smalltalk.tmLanguage
```

The `Library` folder might be hidden by default. Use the Terminal or Finder's *Go ▶︎ Go To Folder…* to access it.

Answer (score 0):

For Smalltalk/X you can download a highlighting package at - [sublime highlighting for smalltalk/X](https://bitbucket.org/-tukanos-/sublime-highlighting-for-smalltalk-x/src/default/) called *Smalltalk.sublime-package*.

You can copy it to the path provided by @MartinW above.